# how to edit element with axios api call by editing a text area - React typescript & axios

Tags: javascript, typescript, react-hooks, axios, react-typescript

I'm working on a react tsx app with symfony backend and axios to fetch my API.

In my "prospects" page,I added a textarea field with a submit button which creates a comment in my api, it works well, what I'm trying to accomplish here is :

-When I post a comment, i would like for its content to stay written in the textarea, and when I edit the textarea and hit submit, the post should be updated with the updated areatext content.

```
import {useRef, useState} from "react";
import CreateComment from "../Modal/CreateComment";
import {useMutation} from "react-query";
import {COMMENT_URL} from "../utils/config";
import axios from "axios";
import {useAuth} from "../../../../utilities/hooks/Auth_hook";
import {notify} from "../../../../utilities/components/Toaster";
import {ToastContainer} from "react-toastify";
import getErrorMessage from "../../../../utilities/helpers/getErrorMessage";


const ProspectComment = ({prospectId}: any) => {
    const [showModalCreate, setShowModalCreate] = useState(false);
    const [showModalQuickCreate, setShowModalQuickCreate] = useState(true);
    const textAreaRef = useRef(null);
    enum Mode {
        create = "create",
        edit = "edit",
    }

    const [message, setMessage] = useState<string>("");
    const [error, setError] = useState<boolean>(false);
    const [mode, setMode] = useState<Mode>(Mode.create);
    const [toEdit, setToEdit] = useState<string>("");
    const {token} = useAuth();

    const makeComment = (token: string | null) => {
        return async (data: any) => {
            const response = await axios.post(`${COMMENT_URL}`, data, {
                headers: {
                    Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
                    "Content-Type": "application/ld+json",
                },
            });
        };
    };

    const updateComment = (token: string | null) => {
        return async (data: any) => {
            const response = await axios.patch(`${COMMENT_URL}/${sessionStorage.getItem("currentComment")}`, data, {
                headers: {
                    Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
                    "Content-Type": "application/merge-patch+json",
                    Accept: "application/ld+json",
                },
            });
            return response.data;
        };
    };

    const makeCommentMutation = useMutation(makeComment(token), {
        onSuccess: () => {
            notify(true, "Successfully commented on this agent ");
            setMode(Mode.edit);
            setShowModalQuickCreate(true);
            setShowModalCreate(false);
        },
        onError: (error: any) => {
            let msg = getErrorMessage(error, "Error while creating comment");
            notify(false, msg);
        },
    });


    const updateCommentMutation = useMutation(updateComment(token), {
        onSuccess: () => {
            notify(true, "Comment updated successfully");
            setShowModalQuickCreate(true);
            setMessage("");
            setMode(Mode.edit);
            setShowModalQuickCreate(true);
            setToEdit("");
            setShowModalCreate(false);
        },
        onError: (error: any) => {
            let msg = getErrorMessage(error, "Error while updating comment");
            notify(false, msg);
        },
    });


    const cancelCommentCreate = () => {
        if (error) setError(false);
        setMessage("");
        setMode(Mode.create);
        setShowModalQuickCreate(true);
    };

    const saveCommentCreate = () => {
        if (!(message?.trim().length > 0)){
            return setError(true);
        }
        setMode(Mode.create)
        if (mode === Mode.create) {
            makeCommentMutation.mutate({
                prospect: `/api/prospects/${prospectId}`,
                message,
            });
        } else {
            updateCommentMutation.mutate({
                prospect: `/api/prospects/${prospectId}`,
                message,
            });
        }
        return
    };

    return (
        <>
            <ToastContainer/>
            <CreateComment
                open={showModalCreate}
                saveItem={saveCommentCreate}
                cancel={cancelCommentCreate}
                mode={mode}
            />
            <div>
                <div>
                    {/* USER COMMENT */}

                    {showModalQuickCreate && (
                        <>
              <textarea
                  name="message"
                  id="message"
                  ref={textAreaRef}
                  onFocus={(e) => e.target.select()}
                  value={message}
                  onChange={(e) => {
                      const value = e.target.value;
                      if (value.length < 1) setError(true);
                      else if (error) setError(false);
                      setMessage(e.target.value);
                  }}
                  cols={10}
                  rows={5}
                 
                  placeholder="Type your comment"
              ></textarea>
                        </>
                    )}

                    {showModalQuickCreate && (
                        <div>
                            <button
                                onClick={() => {
                                    saveCommentCreate();
                                }}
                                disabled={makeCommentMutation?.isLoading}
                            >
                                {makeCommentMutation?.isLoading ||
                                updateCommentMutation?.isLoading ? (
                                    <span></span>
                                ) : mode === Mode.edit ? (
                                    "Save"
                                ) : (
                                    "Send"
                                )}
                            </button>
                        </div>
                    )}


                </div>
            </div>
        </>
    );
};

export default ProspectComment;
```

i tried to add a variable when posting a comment that will contain the id of the comment and then use it in the patch method for axios but didn't work (kept getting no route errors)